# Do we need a tag for 'replication-paper'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest we need a [replication-paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication-paper) tag.

This would be about replication papers, and ***not*** the narrow issue of  irreproducibility. The replication paper issue in its own right is touched upon frequently, but doesn't seem to get acknowledged as such:

- Are replication papers respected? as much as original research? What is their career value?
- My research (some replication, some original ideas) produced negative results. Is this publishable (e.g. as a replication paper)?
- How to go about trying to replicate someone else's work?
- What are reasonable expectations of reproducibility?
- Best practices to make my published work/results/code/data replicatable?
- How to get access to data? Can I expect access to source code? with attached restrictions?
- How to phrase correspondence with authors if I encounter problems with irreproducibility?
- How to handle replication when the code/data are not open-source/ have restrictions attached?

Examples:

- [Have researchers any incentive to publish negative or confirmatory results?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36794/have-researchers-any-incentive-to-publish-negative-or-confirmatory-results)
- [Where do researchers get the money to replicate others' work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41845/where-do-researchers-get-the-money-to-replicate-others-work/)
- [How to deal with papers/authors that provide no details of implementation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/how-to-deal-with-papers-authors-that-provide-no-details-of-implementation)
- [Can I request the code behind a research paper from the author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26159/can-i-request-the-code-behind-a-research-paper-from-the-author)
- [Why do many talented scientists write horrible software?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/why-do-many-talented-scientists-write-horrible-software)
- [(Answer) How can I get into computer science research as a high school student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42763/how-can-i-get-into-computer-science-research-as-a-high-school-student/42807#42807)
- [How accurate are published papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41812/how-accurate-are-published-papers/)
- [Should I cite all R packages I used?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/should-i-cite-all-r-packages-i-used/)
- [What to do when research leads to poor results?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/what-to-do-when-research-leads-to-poor-results)

There are 106 hits for 'replication'.

Answer (score 1):

The number of search hits for a keyword is not necessarily a good indication of how much it is needed as a tag.

If we limit the search to questions containing "replication," there are [fewer results](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=Replication+is%3Aquestion) and many are not relevant (i.e. mention replication only tangentially).

I am of the opinion that [reproducible-research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproducible-research) suffices for the small number of questions about reproducing or replicating someone else's research. (I think it's OK to expand the scope of the tag slightly to accommodate replication.)

Comment: I already said it's not just about irreproducibility. I suggested we need a tag for **replication-paper**, which is separate and is something frequently touched upon. A replication paper is about much much more than the narrow issue of whether something is reproducible. Let me go add clarification to the question.